# Weekly SQL database backup failing

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have a weekly SQL database backup job that is failing. If I look at the end of the history of the job, I see the following messages:

> Executing query "USE [msdb]  ".: 2% complete  End Progress  Progress:
>   2015-06-14 21:27:49.47     Source: Rebuild Index Task      ;
>
> Executing query "ALTER INDEX [DTA_progress_index] ON
>   [dbo].[DTA_pro...".: 4% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2015-06-14
>   21:27:49.47     Source: Rebuild Index Task      ;
>
> Executing query "USE [msdb]  ".: 6% complete  End Progress  Progress:
>   2015-06-14 21:27:49.82     Source: Rebuild Index Task      ;
>
> Executing query "ALTER INDEX [DTA_reports_column_index] ON
>   [dbo].[D...".: 8% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2015-06-14
>   21:27:49.82     Source: Rebuild Index Task      ;
>
> Executing query "USE [msdb]  ".: 10% complete  End Progress 
>   Progress: 2015-06-14 21:27:50.38     Source: Rebuild Index Task      ;
>
> Executing query "ALTER INDEX [PK__DTA_repo__1AA1422F61A66D40] ON
>   [d...".: 12% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2015-06-14 21:27:50.38 
>   Source: Rebuild Index Task      ;
>
> Executing query "USE [msdb]  ".: 14% complete  End Progress 
>   Progress: 2015-06-14 21:27:50.46     Source: Rebuild Index Task      ;
>
> Executing query "ALTER INDEX [DTA_reports_database_index] ON [db... 
>   The package execution fa...  The step failed.

I understand that the DTA indexes are created by the database tuning advisor, so I believe that the job is attempting to alter an index that no longer exists. The question is, how can I change the job so that it now longer attempts to do this?

Comment: have you tried rebuilding the index manually? if you have an do get and error, post that as well.

Comment: There is too much information in the output to retrieve the actual error from the MSDB history. Have you considered separating your backup and index maintenance into separate jobs?

Comment: Thanks Bob and Aaron. I opened up the Maintenance plan and looked at the TSQL, and now I can see the re-indexing lines that are causing the problem.                                                                                         USE [msdb] GO
ALTER INDEX [DTA_progress_index] ON [dbo].[DTA_progress] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH ( PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, ONLINE = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF )                     Is there any way to edit that SQL, or do I need to recreate the maintenance plan. I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: run this SQL by itself in SSMS and see if it returns error. If this is a production server, you may want to find a time in your maintenance windows to do this test becasue if it succeed, your table will be locked during the rebuild

Comment: Hi Bob, I ran the TSQL code from the Maintenance plan manually, and it ran successfully. It only took a second to run. Could the error when running in the maintenance plan be due to locks? The plan is set to run at 9pm, at the same time as several other batch files and SQL jobs are run.

Comment: It just clicked to me what Aaron was saying. even though the last thing you see in the error is "ALTER INDEX [DTA_reports_database_index]" that may not be the thing that caused your job to fail. The error you are seeing maxes out at 4000 characters I believe. Either split the Job, as Aaron suggested, or you could add a step output file to the job step.

Comment: Thanks Aaron and Bob. I switched on the additional logging for the job step in SSMS, when it runs again I will have a look at the results to see what the real problem is. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I looked at the extended error information, and it pointed me to an index that could not be re-indexed in Online mode, only Offline. I removed the re-indexing of that database from the job, and created a new job that works to re-index that database in offline mode. Thanks all for your help!